# How to get username in django_requestlogging

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am using ‘django_requestlogging’ for the log file and I have followed [django_requestlogging](https://pypi.org/project/django-requestlogging/) this link and configured it as per the steps given.

I am not getting the username in the log file instead of that I am getting “-”.

Please find the code details.

**step1**.Installed application

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
-------
------
'django_requestlogging',
]
```

**step2:**
Created Middleware

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
from django_requestlogging.middleware import LogSetupMiddleware as Original

class LogSetupMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin, Original):
    pass
```

**step3:**
used in settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
‘django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware’,
‘django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware’,
‘django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware’,
‘django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware’,
‘django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware’,
‘django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware’,
‘django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware’,
‘user_visit.middleware.UserVisitMiddleware’,
# ‘django_requestlogging.middleware.LogSetupMiddleware’,
‘apple.middleware1.LogSetupMiddleware’
]
```

**step4:**
Configuration

```
import logging
import logging.config
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    # Version of logging
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        # Add an unbound RequestFilter.
        'request': {
            '()': 'django_requestlogging.logging_filters.RequestFilter',
        },
    },
    'formatters': {
        'request_format': {
            'format': '%(remote_addr)s  "%(request_method)s '
            '%(path_info)s %(server_protocol)s" %(http_user_agent)s '
            '%(message)s %(asctime)s',
        },

        'simple': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] - %(levelname)5s -:%(message)3s -" %(username)5s'
        },

    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'filters': ['request'],
            'formatter': 'simple',
        },

        'file': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'Apple00012.log',
            'formatter':'simple'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
       'django': {
            # Add your handlers that have the unbound request filter
            'handlers': ['console','file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
            # Optionally, add the unbound request filter to your
            # application.
            'filters': ['request'],
        },
    },
}
```

In the O/p Log file, I am getting.

```
[2021-01-01 21:53:39,243] - INFO -:"GET /genesysall/ HTTP/1.1" 200 82259 -" -
```

Any help or hint on this how to get the username.

Answer (score 0):

import logging.config

class RequestMiddleware:

```
def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response


def __call__(self, request):
    response = self.get_response(request)
    self.process_request(request, response)
    return response


def process_request(self, request, response):
    user_name = getattr(request.user, 'username', '-')

    if user_name:
        logging.config.dictConfig({
            'version': 1,
            # Version of logging
            'disable_existing_loggers': False,
            'formatters': {

                'simple': {
                    'format': f'[%(asctime)s] - %(levelname)5s -:%(message)3s -> { user_name }'
                },

            },
            'handlers': {
                'file': {
                    'level': 'INFO',
                    'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
                    'filename': 'debug.log',
                    'formatter':'simple'
                },
            },
            'loggers': {
            'django': {
                    # Add your handlers that have the unbound request filter
                    'handlers': ['file'],
                    'level': 'DEBUG',
                    'propagate': True,
                    # Optionally, add the unbound request filter to your
                    # application.
                },
            },
        })
```

Comment: You could explain what this class is designed to do